# Logback configuration daily rotate and zip monthly

Tags: logback

Is it possible to set logback's configuration to create a .log file every day and keep 30 files then zip the files in one zip and start to create .log again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ...

> create a .log file every day and keep 30 files

... using a `RollingFileAppender` with a `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`. Here's an example:

```
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logFile.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
      <!-- retain 30 days logs -->
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>...</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```

But there is no Logback appender which will then do this:

> zip the files in one zip and start to create .log again

For that you could:

- Write your own appender (plenty of details on this [in the docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#WriteYourOwnAppender))

Or

- Handle this outside Logback; you are dealing with files on a file system so a cron job which runs a shell script which finds all files from the last *n* days and zips them up and then deletes them would do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. I have already come to the same solution.. I was wondering if there is a way to do it with only logback configuration. I was thinking to use FixedWindowRollingPolicy but can't fit my case.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Note that `<maxHistory>` property is optional and so can be omitted. For further details you can refer to the documentation at https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy

Comment: Just for clarity: `ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender` extends `ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender`