# why is my logback Daily RollingFileAppender not rolling and still appending to one file?

Tags: spring, logging, logback

I use Logback through Lombok and the @Slf4j annotation, within a Spring application, so my logging configuration is in a `logback-spring.xml` file. The general logging is working, but the problem is I'm trying to create a daily log file, and it is instead continuing to append to the single log file. I used the config from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520686/logback-configuration-daily-rotate-and-zip-monthly) but it is still not working.

Here is the appender section of my `spring-logback.xml` file:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/myApp.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>logs/myApp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>2MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

</appender>
```

I then found another [SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602415/rolling-logback-logs-on-filesize-and-time), and tried that configuration as well, but it's still not working. Here's that configuration:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/myApp.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>myApp-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>

</appender>
```

Is it possible that it's due to Spring, and I need to configure it another way?

Comment: In the second configuration, fileNamePattern is missing `log/`. Can you try adding that and test it. To test whether the trigger is working correctly, you can change the fileNamePattern to include minutes. Ex: `<fileNamePattern>logs/myApp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log</fileNamePattern>` and the log file should be rolled over every minute.

Comment: Is that appender even used? You only show us part of your configuration, so it’s possible the problem lies in the ommitted bits.

Comment: Yes the FILE appender is definitely used; I added the ~logs/~ to the fileNamePattern. Still isn't rolling. Is creating the log file logs/myApp.log, not creating the log file with the date pattern in the name of the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget this in your configuration:

```
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>
```

I guest then won't roll until your log file append new line.